# How to add multiple touch locations with multiple bounding boxes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I have two CCSprites on the screen.  One is called _star and the other is called _redStar.

Where it says CGRectContainsPoint, how can I say something like _star.boundingBox OR _redstar.boundingBox, touchLocation.  I'm not sure if this is possible, and if so, I just don't know the syntax.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_physicsNode];

        if(CGRectContainsPoint((_star.boundingBox), touchLocation))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty simple programming task. You use the || like:

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_physicsNode];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(_star.boundingBox, touchLocation) ||
       CGRectContainsPoint(_redstar.boundingBox, touchLocation))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```